# How I can add a JTable to a class extended from JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jscrollpane

I want to create a class and extend it from JScrollPane than I want to add a customized table to it, I want to know is it possible or not?
I put my sample code here

Can I create my table after I call super?

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class myJtableButton extends JScrollPane {
    private JTable __table;
    private JScrollPane __scrollPane;
    private String TableName;


    public myJtableButton(String TableName) {
        super(__table);
        __table = new JTable();

        this.TableName = TableName;

    }
}
```

Comment: See also [Java Coding Style Guide](http://developers.sun.com/sunstudio/products/archive/whitepapers/java-style.pdf).

Comment: There is no need to extend JScrollPane just to add a table (or any component) to the scrollpane.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can create such a class.  Just don't call super in your constructor.  Instead create your table and then set the view of the scroll bar like this:

```
setViewportView(table);
```